# Coordinate Operations Error for NAD83(2011) Alaska Zone 1

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, shapefile, gdalwarp, orthophoto

I am receiving the following error below when running `gdalwarp` to crop an input orthomosaic in the NAD83(2011)-Alaska Zone 1 CRS. The command still runs and the output cropped TIFF file renders fine when opening in QGIS or ArcGIS. What could be causing this error? I am trying to understand if GDAL does not fully support NAD83-Alaska Zone 1. Also, the input GeoTIFF and shapefile are both in NAD83-Alaska Zone 1.

EPSG:6394 info: https://epsg.io/6394

**gdalwarp command:**

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline [shapefile] -crop_to_cutline [input-tif] [output-tif] -wo NUM_THREADS=ALL_CPUS -co BIGTIFF=YES -co TILED=YES -co COMPRESS=JPEG -multi
```

**gdal version:** 3.0.2

Terminal Output:

```
--------------------------------------------
ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `EPSG:6394' to `BOUNDCRS[SOURCECRS[GEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",1116]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]]],TARGETCRS[GEOGCRS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4326]]],ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation from NAD83(2011) to WGS84",METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",ID["EPSG",9606]],PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8605]],PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8606]],PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8607]],PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8608]],PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8609]],PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8610]],PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,ID["EPSG",8611]]]]'
Creating output file that is 185799P x 213951L.
Processing rw-11-29a.tif [1/1] : 0ERROR 6: Cannot find coordinate operations from `EPSG:6394' to `BOUNDCRS[SOURCECRS[GEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",1116]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]]],TARGETCRS[GEOGCRS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],ID["EPSG",4326]]],ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation from NAD83(2011) to WGS84",METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",ID["EPSG",9606]],PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8605]],PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8606]],PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8607]],PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8608]],PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8609]],PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8610]],PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,ID["EPSG",8611]]]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with QGIS or PROJ (the underlaying coordinate reference system/operation/transformation software) but I have some familiarity with coordinate reference system (CRS) and operation well-known text (WKT). This might be a bug in PROJ, because there are minor differences between the source and target CRS definitions for NAD83(2011) which shouldn't cause an error.

However, the error itself says that it can't identify a operation (AKA not-official-terminology-anymore transformation) between 6394 and the target CRS. So (A) the minor differences between the source 6394 WKT definition and the target CRS are causing the pipeline to fail or (B) because the target CRS has a hard-coded operation included, that causes the pipeline creation to fail.

By 'pipeline', I mean a set of one or more operations that convert from the source to the target CRS. In this case, the problem should be in the portion that converts from the input GeoCRS (NAD83(2011) and the output GeoCRS (also NAD83(2011)).

In case (A), the software might not be able to identify the output GeoCRS as 6318 as that identifier isn't part of the WKT. However, the entire output WKT is identified as 6394 so you would think that the software might look up what the GeoCRS should be and get the ID that way. (There are reasons why it might not and be designed that way--people tend to do 'fun' things with WKT strings)

In case (B), The input CRS doesn't have an attached operation to convert it to WGS 84 or another CRS but the output CRS does and may that's causing a problem.

If you can control the output CRS in anyway, you might try omitting the ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION part to see if that helps. The reason why the process works anyway is that NAD83(2011) and WGS 84 are within a meter or so and the operation has zero parameters except for the scale difference which is only 1 ppm.

For clarity, here is a lightly formatted version of 6394 from the EPSG registry:

```
PROJCRS["NAD83(2011) / Alaska zone 1",

BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",
DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)", 
ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]], 
ID["EPSG",7019]], 
ID["EPSG",1116]], 
ID["EPSG",6318]],

CONVERSION["SPCS83 Alaska zone 1 (meters)", 
METHOD["Hotine Oblique Mercator (variant A)",ID["EPSG",9812]],  
PARAMETER["Latitude of projection centre",57,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]], 
PARAMETER["Longitude of projection centre",-133.666666666667,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]], 
PARAMETER["Azimuth of initial line",323.130102361111,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]], 
PARAMETER["Angle from Rectified to Skew Grid",323.130102361111,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9102]]], 
PARAMETER["Scale factor on initial line",0.9999,SCALEUNIT["unity",1,ID["EPSG",9201]]],
PARAMETER["False easting",5000000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]], 
PARAMETER["False northing",-5000000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]]], 
ID["EPSG",15031]], 
CS[Cartesian,2,ID["EPSG",4499]],  
AXIS["Easting (X)",east],  
AXIS["Northing (Y)",north],LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,ID["EPSG",9001]], 
ID["EPSG",6394]]
```

And the target CRS:

```
`BOUNDCRS[SOURCECRS[GEOGCRS["NAD83(2011)",
DATUM["NAD83 (National Spatial Reference System 2011)",
ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101004,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],ID["EPSG",1116]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],
CS[ellipsoidal,2],
AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]],
AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,ID["EPSG",9122]]]]],
TARGETCRS[GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],       
CS[ellipsoidal,2],
AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
ID["EPSG",4326]]],
ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation from NAD83(2011) to WGS84",
METHOD["Position Vector transformation (geog2D domain)",ID["EPSG",9606]],
PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8605]],
PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8606]],
PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,ID["EPSG",8607]],
PARAMETER["X-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8608]],
PARAMETER["Y-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8609]],
PARAMETER["Z-axis rotation",0,ID["EPSG",8610]],
PARAMETER["Scale difference",1,ID["EPSG",8611]]]]'
```

Disclosure: I work for Esri. I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG geodetic registry and was on the WKT2 standard committee.